# read registry key #1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

I wrote a firefox extension and I want to check that it is loaded from a service developed in visual studio 2010 c#.  I have researched and tried numerous different methods to read a key and all I get is:  "Registry read failed: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Here is one method I used:

```
RegistryKey rKey1 = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey rKey2 = rKey1.OpenSubKey("Software\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Extensions");
string strKeyValue = rKey2.GetValue("thing@place.com").ToString();
```

Comment: Where is the null reference surfacing? Which line?

Comment: it seems to do line 2 ok but the error occurs at line 3

Comment: That is certainly because it can't find the specified subkey. You can gradually increase the searched key from simple "Software" to see where it stucks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your service runs under the account that is specified on the service configuration, so it's HKCU may be different than the current user that may be logged into the machine.  To test your code, try running the service under your user account instead of Local System, which is probably what it is running under now.

Comment: I have to run this service from Local System and the service will not know which users ... right now NSIS installer writes the key to HKCU without regard to specific user(s).  And I am looking at the key in HKCU in regedit.

Comment: If the installer writes to HKCU, it will only write to that hive for the user who runs the installer.  I would bet if you create multiple users on a test machine and run the installer as one of them, the other one would not have this key.  HKLM may be the place to put the key, which is essentially all users, instead of just the current user.